# NSDateComponents - EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Basic question to which I'm sure there is a simple answer.

I'm trying to get the timestamp of a photo. When I try to access the NSDateComponents to retrieve a specific date element (say "day" for example), I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

First, the relevant bits of my code:

```
// formattedDateString is a string representing the "DateTimeOriginal" EXIF property extracted from the image   
NSDate *takenAt = [[NSDate alloc] initWithString:formattedDateString];
NSLog(@"date: %@", takenAt); // prints= date: 2010-01-10 03:25:00 -0500

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSLog(@"cal: %@", gregorian); // prints= cal: <__NSCFCalendar: 0x10020b570>

NSUInteger unitFlags =  (NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit);      
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components: unitFlags 
                                            fromDate: takenAt
                               ];

int days = [components hour];
NSLog(@"comp: %@", days); // thrown error= Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”
```

If I comment out the final line: *NSLog(@"comp: %@", days);*  the code executes successfully.

I've tried a few variants on this but the bottom line is that any time I send a message to *components* to access a property the "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error is raised.

The research I did seems to indicate that this is typically the result of an uninitialized pointer or an object that I've tried to release that isn't mine to release. From what I can tell that's not the case here.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for shedding some light on this for me. This is one of my first explorations in Objective-C.

[NSDateComponents class reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `%@` as the format-specifier for an integer. You need to use `%d`.

When you use `%@`, the `NSLog` function will treat the argument as an object, and send it the `description` message. What really happens, is that the runtime tries to dereference the argument (the integer) but because it is not a valid pointer, you get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception.

Comment: That my friend is an excellent answer/explanation and a ridiculous mistake on my part. Thanks for the help, much appreciated!