# Objective C EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)

Tags: objective-c

I am new at objective c,

I am taking two dates and getting the number of days in between:

```
NSString *start = @"2010-12-01";
NSString *end = @"2010-12-02";

NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *startDate = [f dateFromString:start];
NSDate *endDate = [f dateFromString:end];

NSDateComponents *components;
NSInteger days;

components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSDayCalendarUnit
fromDate: startDate toDate: endDate options: 0];

days = [components day];
```

When I try to assign days to `cell.textLable.text = days`, but I get this error message:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x1)
```

cell is this `SGridAutoMultiLineCell *cell;` what does error mean and how do I fix it. the number that is being returned is 1.

Comment: Same mistake: [NSDateComponents EXC_BAD_ACCESS error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2226286)

Comment: I dont understand there answer, should I try cell.textLabel.text = NSLog(@"%ld", days) ?

Comment: Probably more like `cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", days];`.

Comment: I would recommend that you have a look at [Good resources for learning ObjC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1374660). The Big Nerd Ranch books are excellent, and lots of people like the Stanford iOS course on iTunes U.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", days];
```

Your current code (`cell.textLable.text = days;`) is passing an integer to a field that expects an `NSString` pointer. When the component tries to dereference that value (`1`) as a pointer, the crash occurs because `1` is not currently a valid memory location.

The code above will construct an `NSString` containing the `days` value.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning an integer value (1, the number of days between Dec 1st and 2nd) to the label which expects an instance of `NSString`.  This is why the error message says the address is 0x1- it is treating the integer value of 1 as an address of an object in memory.  As pointed out in the comments it's necessary to first convert the integer to a string.  The easiest way is using `-stringWithFormat:` but you may want to perform locale-specific formatting.